# How to link Firebase authenticated users to related Firestore database (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Suppose I have a user that has logged in using Firebase for authentication. How do i go about linking that authenticated user to a specified document.
For example a newly created user "Zoboomafoo" would have his own document with all of his data stored in there. I would imagine on creation of a new user the document would be created and linked, its just i dont have any idea how to go about it (newbie).

image attached is what i assume it would look like

[image: Firebase Firestore console]

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post detailing exactly how one might do this.  It involves:

1. Writing a Cloud Function that triggers on new user creation
2. Writing a document for that user, identified by their UID, into a users collection
3. Client code waiting (via a Firestore document listener) on the creation of that document before allowing the user to progress into the app.
4. Using security rules to secure access to the document so that only the Cloud Function can write it (so that the system can't be compromised by a malicious user).

https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07